# kura 3.0.0-remote deployment of deployment package via MQTT works on emulator but fails on raspberry pi 3B

Tags: java, raspberry-pi, osgi, mqtt, kura

Remote deployment of deployment package via MQTT works perfectly when kura is running on emulator, but when I send the same MQTT message while kura is running on a raspberry pi the deployment fails.

Following are kura logs on pi -

```
2017-07-06 11:36:37,396 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - Message arrived on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/download
2017-07-06 11:36:37,458 [MQTT Call: test-client] WARN  o.e.k.c.d.DataServiceListenerS - No registered listeners. Ignoring onMessageArrived
```

After putting some logs in the developer workspace and then deploying it on the raspberry pi, the logs are as follows -

```
2017-07-06 11:36:37,391 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.d.DataServiceListenerS - m_listeners -- >>[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudServiceImpl@17ee701]
2017-07-06 11:36:37,393 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.d.DataServiceListenerS - in for, listener -- >>[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudServiceImpl@17ee701]
2017-07-06 11:36:37,396 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - Message arrived on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/download
2017-07-06 11:36:37,398 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - payload
2017-07-06 11:36:37,445 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - cloud clients is -------------------->1
2017-07-06 11:36:37,448 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@12629da]
2017-07-06 11:36:37,451 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - cloudClient.getApplicationId()ASSET-V1
2017-07-06 11:36:37,453 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  o.e.k.c.c.CloudServiceImpl - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
2017-07-06 11:36:37,458 [MQTT Call: test-client] WARN  o.e.k.c.d.DataServiceListenerS - No registered listeners. Ignoring onMessageArrived
```

As compared to the emulator logs which are as follows-

```
16:33:04,172 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:436  - Message arrived on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/test-client/DEPLOY-V2/EXEC/download
16:33:04,173 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:437  - payload
16:33:04,180 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:451  - cloud clients is -------------------->5
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:454  - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@6b00be9, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@2e57dfa3, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@5d6b70cb, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@60a2beb1, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@664b1e0f]
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:455  - cloudClient.getApplicationId()CONF-V1
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:456  - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:454  - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@6b00be9, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@2e57dfa3, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@5d6b70cb, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@60a2beb1, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@664b1e0f]
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:455  - cloudClient.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,181 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:456  - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,182 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:459  - $EDC
16:33:04,182 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:460  - $EDC
16:33:04,182 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:462  - prefix are equal
16:33:04,182 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:476  - validMessagetrue
16:33:04,185 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:454  - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@6b00be9, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@2e57dfa3, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@5d6b70cb, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@60a2beb1, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@664b1e0f]
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:455  - cloudClient.getApplicationId()CMD-V1
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:456  - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:454  - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@6b00be9, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@2e57dfa3, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@5d6b70cb, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@60a2beb1, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@664b1e0f]
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:455  - cloudClient.getApplicationId()myapp
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:456  - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:454  - in for loop cloud client is -------------------->[org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@6b00be9, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@2e57dfa3, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@5d6b70cb, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@60a2beb1, org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.CloudClientImpl@664b1e0f]
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:455  - cloudClient.getApplicationId()ASSET-V1
16:33:04,186 [MQTT Call: test-client] INFO  CloudServiceImpl:456  - kuraTopic.getApplicationId()DEPLOY-V2
16:33:04,191 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  CloudDeploymentHandlerV2:474  - About to download and install package at URL http://172.30.66.77:8081/RemoteDeploymentTest/hello_world.dp
16:33:04,191 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  CloudDeploymentHandlerV2:483  - Downloading package from URL: http://172.30.66.77:8081/RemoteDeploymentTest/hello_world.dp
16:33:04,193 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_12RV8P8UJBOP6IIRNOFC7OJH62/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_PFLTDP6JEU47S4U876D1356BOE, priority: 1
16:33:04,199 [pool-11-thread-1] INFO  DownloadImpl:110  - To download
16:33:04,202 [pool-1-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_12RV8P8UJBOP6IIRNOFC7OJH62/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_PFLTDP6JEU47S4U876D1356BOE, priority: 1
16:33:04,204 [DataServiceImpl:Submit] INFO  MqttDataTransport:516  - Publishing message on topic: $EDC/amir-kura/CLIENT_12RV8P8UJBOP6IIRNOFC7OJH62/DEPLOY-V2/REPLY/REQUEST_PFLTDP6JEU47S4U876D1356BOE with QoS: 0
16:33:04,395 [pool-14-thread-1] INFO  HttpDownloadCountingOutputStream:107  - Content-lenght: 1736
16:33:04,396 [pool-14-thread-1] INFO  DownloadImpl:82  - 0% downloaded
16:33:04,402 [pool-14-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:441  - Storing message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_12RV8P8UJBOP6IIRNOFC7OJH62/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download, priority: 1
16:33:04,405 [pool-14-thread-1] INFO  DataServiceImpl:444  - Stored message on topic :$EDC/#account-name/CLIENT_12RV8P8UJBOP6IIRNOFC7OJH62/DEPLOY-V2/NOTIFY/test-client/download, priority: 1
16:33:04,406 [pool-14-thread-1] INFO  DownloadImpl:82  - 4% downloaded
```

The download and installation then completes on the emulator as expected.
Is there something wrong with the installation of kura on the raspberry pi? How do I solve this?
`

Output of `ss` command -

```
osgi> ss
"Framework is launched."


id  State       Bundle
0   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi_3.11.1.v20160708-1632
                Fragments=4
1   ACTIVE      org.json_1.0.0.v201011060100
2   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3_1.1.0
3   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.cm_1.1.200.v20160324-1850
4   RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.sun.misc_1.0.0
                Master=0
5   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.common_3.8.0.v20160509-1230
6   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.registry_3.6.100.v20160223-2218
7   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.registry_1.1.400.v20150715-1528
8   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.console_1.1.200.v20150929-1405
9   ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.ds_1.4.400.v20160226-2036
10  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.event_1.3.200.v20160324-1850
11  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.io_1.1.100.v20150430-1834
12  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.metatype_1.4.200.v20160324-1850
13  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.util_1.0.500.v20130404-1337
14  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.services_3.5.100.v20160504-1419
15  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.osgi.util_3.3.100.v20150423-1351
16  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.command_0.10.0.v201209301215
17  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime_0.10.0.v201209301036
18  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.gogo.shell_0.10.0.v201212101605
19  ACTIVE      org.knowhowlab.osgi.monitoradmin_1.0.2
20  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.dependencymanager_3.0.0
21  ACTIVE      org.apache.felix.deploymentadmin_0.9.5
22  ACTIVE      osgi.cmpn_4.3.0.201111022214
23  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.wireadmin_1.0.600.v20150715-1528
24  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.jetty_3.3.0.v20160324-1850
25  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet_1.3.1.v20160808-1329
26  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.continuation_9.3.9.v20160517
27  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.http_9.3.9.v20160517
28  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.io_9.3.9.v20160517
29  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.security_9.3.9.v20160517
30  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.server_9.3.9.v20160517
31  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.servlet_9.3.9.v20160517
32  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.jetty.util_9.3.9.v20160517
33  ACTIVE      javax.servlet_3.1.0.v201410161800
34  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.fileupload_1.3.2
35  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.io_2.4.0
36  ACTIVE      slf4j.api_1.7.21
                Fragments=38
37  ACTIVE      jcl.over.slf4j_1.7.21
38  RESOLVED    slf4j.log4j12_1.7.21
                Master=36
39  RESOLVED    log4j_1.2.17
                Fragments=40
40  RESOLVED    log4j.apache-log4j-extras_1.1.0
                Master=39
41  RESOLVED    minimal-json_0.9.4
42  ACTIVE      org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.3.0
43  RESOLVED    com.codeminders.hidapi.armv6hf_1.1.100
                Master=44
44  ACTIVE      com.codeminders.hidapi_1.1.100
                Fragments=43
45  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm.armv6hf_1.2.100
                Master=46
46  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.soda.dk.comm_1.2.100
                Fragments=45
47  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.lang3_3.4.0
48  ACTIVE      org.usb4java_1.2.100
49  ACTIVE      usb4java-javax_1.2.100
50  RESOLVED    jdk.dio.armv6hf_1.0.100
                Master=51
51  RESOLVED    jdk.dio_1.0.100
                Fragments=50
52  ACTIVE      org.apache.commons.net_3.1.0.v201205071737
53  RESOLVED    org.apache.commons.exec_1.3.0
54  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.api_1.2.0
55  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core_1.0.100
56  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.certificates_1.0.100
57  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud_1.1.0
58  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.comm_1.0.100
59  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration_1.1.0
60  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto_1.0.100
61  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment_1.1.100
62  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.log_1.0.100
63  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.net_1.0.100
64  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.core.status_1.0.100
65  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent_1.0.100
66  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.clock_1.0.100
67  STARTING    org.eclipse.kura.linux.command_1.0.5
68  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.position_1.0.100
69  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.linux.usb.armv6hf_1.0.100
                Master=70
70  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.usb_1.0.100
                Fragments=69
71  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.bluetooth_1.0.100
72  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.watchdog_1.0.100
73  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.camel.sun.misc_1.0.0
                Master=74
74  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-core_2.17.2
                Fragments=73
75  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-core-osgi_2.17.2
76  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-kura_2.17.2
77  ACTIVE      org.apache.camel.camel-stream_2.17.2
78  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel_1.2.0
79  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory_1.1.0
80  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml_1.0.100
81  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.asset.provider_1.0.0
82  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.asset.cloudlet.provider_1.0.0
83  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.asset.helper.provider_1.0.0
84  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.driver.helper.provider_1.0.0
85  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.localization_1.0.0
                Fragments=86
86  RESOLVED    org.eclipse.kura.localization.resources_1.0.0
                Master=85
87  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.util_1.0.0
88  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider_1.0.0
89  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.wire.helper.provider_1.0.0
90  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.wire.provider_1.0.0
91  RESOLVED    com.gwt.user_1.0.100
92  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.web2_2.0.100
93  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.gpio_1.0.100
94  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.linux.net_1.0.100
95  ACTIVE      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin_1.0.100
96  ACTIVE      org.tigris.mtoolkit.iagent.rpc_3.0.0.20110411-0918
97  ACTIVE      TemperatureSensor_1.0.0.201706291356
98  ACTIVE      onvif_plugin_1.0.0.201706301358
99  ACTIVE      Lwm2mDeviceDiscovery_1.0.0.201706231445
```

Output of `ls` command-

```
osgi> ls
All Components:
ID  State           Component Name          Located in bundle
1   Active      org.eclipse.equinox.event           org.eclipse.equinox.event(bid=10)
2   Active      org.eclipse.kura.data.DataService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
3   Active      org.eclipse.kura.db.DbService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
4   Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.data.transport.mqtt.MqttDataTransport         org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
5   Active      org.eclipse.kura.ssl.SslManagerService          org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
6   Active      org.eclipse.kura.system.SystemService           org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
7   Active      org.eclipse.kura.system.SystemAdminService      org.eclipse.kura.core(bid=55)
8   Active      org.eclipse.kura.certificate.CertificatesService    org.eclipse.kura.core.certificates(bid=56)
9   Active      org.eclipse.kura.cloud.CloudService         org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=57)
10  Registered      org.eclipse.kura.cloud.CloudCallService     org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=57)
11  Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud.factory.DefaultCloudServiceFactory          org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=57)
12  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.cloud.app.command.CommandCloudApp          org.eclipse.kura.core.cloud(bid=57)
13  Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.comm.CommConnectionFactory    org.eclipse.kura.core.comm(bid=58)
14  Active      org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration.CloudConfigurationHandler           org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration(bid=59)
15  Active      org.eclipse.kura.configuration.ConfigurationService org.eclipse.kura.core.configuration(bid=59)
16  Active      org.eclipse.kura.crypto.CryptoService           org.eclipse.kura.core.crypto(bid=60)
17  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment.CloudDeploymentHandlerV2           org.eclipse.kura.core.deployment(bid=61)
18  Active      org.eclipse.kura.log.LoggerService          org.eclipse.kura.core.log(bid=62)
19  Active      org.eclipse.kura.status.CloudConnectionStatusService    org.eclipse.kura.core.status(bid=64)
20  Active      org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent           org.eclipse.kura.deployment.agent(bid=65)
21  Active      org.eclipse.kura.clock.ClockService         org.eclipse.kura.linux.clock(bid=66)
22  Registered      org.eclipse.kura.command.CommandService     org.eclipse.kura.linux.command(bid=67)
23  Active      org.eclipse.kura.position.PositionService       org.eclipse.kura.linux.position(bid=68)
24  Active      org.eclipse.kura.usb.UsbService         org.eclipse.kura.linux.usb(bid=70)
25  Active      org.eclipse.kura.bluetooth.BluetoothService     org.eclipse.kura.linux.bluetooth(bid=71)
26  Active      org.eclipse.kura.watchdog.WatchdogService       org.eclipse.kura.linux.watchdog(bid=72)
27  Active      org.eclipse.kura.camel.KuraCloudComponentResolver   org.eclipse.kura.camel(bid=78)
28  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory.CamelFactory           org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory(bid=79)
29  Active      org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory.CamelCloudServiceFactory           org.eclipse.kura.camel.cloud.factory(bid=79)
30  Active      org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml.XmlRouterComponent       org.eclipse.kura.camel.xml(bid=80)
31  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.asset          org.eclipse.kura.asset.provider(bid=81)
32  Active      org.eclipse.kura.asset.cloudlet         org.eclipse.kura.asset.cloudlet.provider(bid=82)
33  Active      org.eclipse.kura.asset.AssetService         org.eclipse.kura.asset.helper.provider(bid=83)
34  Active      org.eclipse.kura.driver.DriverService           org.eclipse.kura.driver.helper.provider(bid=84)
35  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.CloudPublisher        org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
36  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.CloudSubscriber       org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
37  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.DbWireRecordFilter    org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
38  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.DbWireRecordStore     org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
39  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.Fifo          org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
40  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.Logger            org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
41  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.RegexFilter       org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
42  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.Timer         org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
43  Unsatisfied     org.eclipse.kura.wire.WireAsset         org.eclipse.kura.wire.component.provider(bid=88)
44  Active      org.eclipse.kura.wire.WireHelperService         org.eclipse.kura.wire.helper.provider(bid=89)
45  Registered      org.eclipse.kura.wire.WireServiceCommand    org.eclipse.kura.wire.provider(bid=90)
46  Active      org.eclipse.kura.wire.WireService           org.eclipse.kura.wire.provider(bid=90)
47  Active      org.eclipse.kura.web.Console            org.eclipse.kura.web2(bid=92)
48  Active      org.eclipse.kura.gpio.GPIOService           org.eclipse.kura.linux.gpio(bid=93)
49  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.NetworkService         org.eclipse.kura.linux.net(bid=94)
50  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.dns.DnsMonitorService      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
51  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.EthernetMonitorService     org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
52  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin.FirewallConfigurationServiceorg.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
53  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.CellularMonitorService     org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
54  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin.NetworkAdminService      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
55  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.admin.NetworkConfigurationService  org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
56  Active      org.eclipse.kura.net.WifiMonitorService         org.eclipse.kura.net.admin(bid=95)
57  Active      TemperatureSensor           TemperatureSensor(bid=97)
58  Active      onvif_plugin            onvif_plugin(bid=98)
59  Active      Lwm2mDeviceDiscovery            Lwm2mDeviceDiscovery(bid=99)
```

Comment: On the Raspberry Pi, can you please login to the OSGi console (telnet localhost 5002) and provide the output of the 'ss' and 'ls' commands?

Comment: @David I've added the output of `ss` and `ls` commands

Comment: The CloudDeploymentHandlerV2 component is not resolving correctly. Can you please issue the command 'comp 17' from the OSGi console? Can you also double check /var/log/kura.log and /var/log/kura-console.log for errors?